# Best technique for creating sample content on Drupal 9 programatically within module

Tags: drupal, drush

I have created a drupal 9 custom module with new content types and fields.  I would like to create a sample node when the module is installed.

**What is considered the best method for creating a sample node programatically?**

I looked at using migrate and migrate_tools and building YAML files.  This is promising but have issues with current versions of drush 10.6 and migrate 5.  It looks like there is a fix in dev, but I wondered what everyone else does.  My preference is to not depend on a module, unless there are compelling reasons (like easy maintenance of test cases or sample data)
thanks

Comment: you should probably post this to drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have had success with the [default content module](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) in the past

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a hook:

1. When you install the module, use this hook *[hook_install](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/9.0.x)*
2. When you update the module, use this hook *[hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x)*

In the hook, you have to implements the correct logic:

```
$node = Node::create([
    'type'        => 'article',
    'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
    'field_image' => [
      'target_id' => $file->id(),
      'alt' => 'Hello world',
      'title' => 'Goodbye world'
    ],
]);
$node->save();
```